# resize images over a certain size only

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress plugin to import blog posts off other sites using RSS feeds. The imported posts contain images which I have set to a uniform size using css

```
img {
    width:200px !important;
}
```

This works OK, since only the width size is set the height adjusts to the correct proportion for the original image, and the !important overrides the image size set in the imported posts.

However there are also social-media share images in the imported posts (e.g. from feedburner etc.) which I do not want to resize, e.g.

[image]

Can I add a filter to the css image size to only apply to images over a certain size (e.g. over 100 pixels wide)?

N.B. I tried adding this in the header

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("myDivClass").css(img{ width:200px !important;});
 });
</script>
```

Where the div with the images I want to resize is

```html
<DIV class="myDivClass">
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: Interesting, but I have never watched that it is possible by css, maybe you can try with javascript or since the wordpress plugin.

Comment: is it possible to set a class name? If not , then can you target social media images alone by css ? like img[src=*"facebook.png"]

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose image using div class.

For example your code is:

```
<div class="parentofall">
    <div class="firstparent">
        <img src="imageurl">
    </div>
    <div class="secondparent">
        <img src="imageurl">
    </div>
    <div class="thirdparent">
        <img src="imageurl">
    </div>
</div>
```

Your css should like to this:

```
.parentofall .firstparent img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

To choose selected image, or you can just simply choose firstparent without parentofall.

Another way of go to selected image is:

```
.parentofall > firstparent img {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The div is nested about 12 levels deep, is there any way I can refer to it in the css without specifying the parent divs?

Answer (score 0):

Used this in the end

```js
    <script>
 
    $( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".MyDivClass img").width(200); 
    });
 
    </script>
```